# Indirect Download links in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I Want to give users, link to my files on server but I dont want to get them direct link
with asp.net C#

for example :

http://www.DomainName.com/Files/Downloads/setup.zip

Convert to

http://www.DomainName.com/Files/?filename=setup

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? Read this other question for some help to point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386825/how-to-track-downloads-with-asp-net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a page, something like `DownloadMgr.aspx`  for example, that reads the file name from the query string and writes it to the response stream.

Something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string[] allowedExtensions = new string[] {".pdf",".zip",".txt", ".png"};
      if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
      {
          if (Request.QueryString["File"] != null)
          {
             if (Request.QueryString["File"].Contains("pdf"))
                 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; //varies depending on the file being streamed
              Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Request.QueryString["File"]);
              if(allowedFiles.Contains(Path.GetExtension(Request.QueryString["File"])))
                  Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(Request.QueryString["File"]));
           }
      }
}
```

Now all your links can be like: `http://youhost.com/DownloadMgr.aspx?File=abc.pdf`

Comment: I would add something to prevent arbitrary files from being downloaded; as this example is written, someone could use this to download your `web.config`, or what ever else.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Great observation. Added some logic to prevent this.

Comment: Also add some sort of error message / feedback to the page for when the file cannot be downloaded due to security checks or system errors.

Comment: A generic handler is more appropriate than an aspx file for this

Comment: @mike absolutely. I may post an answer with an example later. It's just a bit trickier since you have to register it and all but definitely a better approach.

Comment: A mechanism needs to be implemented to prevent people from sharing the download links on forums, etc.

Comment: @Icarus you don't have to register an ashx file.