# SaveFileDialog Save Button Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, savefiledialog

Okay I have this scenario over here. I'm pointing a URL to users to allow them to start the download. The download button has a navigateURL with something like www.mydomainname/files/abc.mp3. So when the user clicks it, it will automatically pop up the SaveFileDialog to allow the user to choose their save destination. My question is, do we have any access to the events of button click in the SaveFileDialog? Like FileOk event?
What I want to achieve is that I want to track the number of times the file is being downloaded. Any pointer would be very much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154856/track-file-download-hits-count-in-asp-net Check out the answer to this question. This seems to be a more appropriate approach.

Comment: will the handler adds to the count if the user decides to cancel the download?

Comment: There is no way to really know that. A system for that would be much more difficult. Plus, once the download starts, it's handled by the browser from that point on. I can't think of a way of doing this that wouldn't be a huge security threat if it was possible.

Comment: alright then, i might mark your suggestion as answer if u write it out nicely since I'm using your suggestion now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Track File Download hits/count in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154856/track-file-download-hits-count-in-asp-net)

Check out the answer to this question. This seems to be a more appropriate approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the FileName property is empty. If possible, it might also be worth using sever logs to monitor that if you allow hotlinking as tracking the dialog won't track every possible way to download the file.

Comment: hmm, yeah I was a little bit skeptical about this savefiledialog as well. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the stream sending the file completes, add a log to the database and that would help you generate reports or do a simple SQL to get back the number of times a song is downloaded.

Comment: umm, do you have like an example or something? it's a little vague to me